# Facebook graph API : Missing from data in the comments on a group post

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Objective: 
I am using the FB graph API to publish a post on a FB group and want to read all comments and the users public info who have made these comments on that post.

Using the endpoint **//comments?filter=stream** , I am able to read the comments on a particular post. However, I am not getting the user info who have made the comment and getting the following data:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "created_time": "2019-11-19T18:43:40+0000",
      "message": "XXXXXX", //User comment
      "id": "123123123123123" //Comment Id
    },
    {
      "created_time": "2019-11-19T18:49:47+0000",
      "message": "XXXXXXXXX", //user comment 
      "id": "2232312312444" //Comment FB Id
    },    
  ]
}
```

I am not getting the from object i.e

```
"from" => array:2 [
    "name" => "USER PUBLIC NAME"
    "id" => "USER FB ID"
  ]
```

The App is live and approved and it has requested all permissions related to groups i.e  "publish_to_groups", "groups_access_member_info"

Here is the FB documentation that I am following:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v5.0/comment

In this documentation, FB mention the **From** field as

> from | The person that made this comment | User

Althought, The same is working for posts shared on FB pages

Comment: The documentation is vague on under which circumstances that is still supposed to work IMHO. Is the app live and has everything related to this functionality reviewed & approved? If not, I think at most you could expect to get that data from users that actually have a role in your app at that point.

Comment: I have updated the documentation. Kindly review

Comment: I guess you'd have to ask Facebook (bug report), if that is actually supposed to work under these conditions then.